# How to use Meteor Sessions between two different components?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I am creating a lobby system for a game in Meteor. Users enter the lobby code and their name to enter the lobby. I want to use Meteor Sessions to identify the current user in the lobby. I am having trouble with the Meteor Sessions because I have `Session.set("currentPlayer", playerId);` in a component called join.js, and I have `Session.get("currentPlayer");` in a component called party.js (where the lobby is rendered).

After a user joins the lobby, they are routed to the url with the lobby code. When I use `Session.setPersistent("currentPlayer", playerId);` from https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session, I can identify the current user, but the current user is persistent over all tabs in the browser. I do not want this. I want the name of the user that joined the lobby to be returned by `Session.get("currentPlayer");`

I have also consoled `Session.get("currentPlayer");` in the join.js component and got the correct value which means that the problem is probably the fact that I am trying to return `Session.get("currentPlayer");` in a new route. What should I do?

Comment: `Session` variables are globals, they don't depend on your route. Why use a Session however when it can only ever contain `Meteor.userId()`? The scope of a Session variable is a single user's session.

Comment: I am not using Meteor Accounts though. I want the users to be temporary. Are sessions the best way to get the Id?

Comment: Are they logged in users? They won't have an _id otherwise. There would be a session id but that has nothing to do with Meteor accounts. The session id won't change during the session either which means you don't need `Session` to store it.

Comment: No, they are not logged in. Every time a user joins the lobby, a Player document is added to the Players mongoDB collection. I want to use a Session to retrieve the Id of the current player. I think the problem is that I have the Session.set and the Session.get in two different js files. Session.set is in join.js and Session.get is in party.js witch is where I display the lobby. How do I fix this?

Comment: `Session` works across js files, it's a global object.